# JavaScript/Node.js operator overload with C++ add-on

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

It's possible to create certain JavaScript objects in C++ with node-addon-api and then expose this objects in the JavaScript context with overloaded operators?

Example: I'm writing a financial software and I have a Decimal class in C++. I'm exposing this decimal class operations in Node.js and I would like to override the +, -, /, * operators.

I know that in pure JavaScript it's not possible to overload operators, but I was wondering if with C++ when defining a JS object there is this possibility with node-addon-api.